# Maximizing $\iiint|(x-z)\times(y-z)|d\mu d\mu d\mu$ over probability measures on the unit sphere

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, potential-theory, spherical-geometry

This is a follow-up question to the one asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351772/maximizing-iiintx-z-timesy-zd-mu-d-mu-d-mu-over-probability-measures-on?noredirect=1#comment881964_351772) (the unit circle case). What probability measure(s) maximize the quantity $\iiint_{\mathbb{S}^2}|(x-z)\times(y-z)|d\mu(x)d\mu(y)d\mu(z)$?

The answer may be uniform measure, by direct analogy to the unit circle problem.